# How to show a different image on the same webpage on a daily basis, automatically?

Tags: html

I need to  have a new product image everyday on a webpage automatically. Product of the day kinda thing.
Just one single image that changes every day with a new one.

The images do not have to be part of a slideshow, nor have to have a player installed, nor have text.

I have a folder with all the images. I have a page on a website where that image should go.

How can I do that?

I'm not a programer nor write code, so I need to find something specific that tells me  step by step, hopefully how I may accomplish this.  I have found several "rotating" scrips but they deal with things like caroussel, or fairly vague as to how go about it etc.

All I need to know is how to create an automatic function that will go to that image folder and insert a picture on that webpage everyday. Oh yeah, the images are not all the same size. 
The web site is hosted by Weebly. (they don't know how to do this btw.)

Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you much in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify an order for your images. If they could be displayed randomly, a simple solution for a non-developer would be to rename your files 1 to n, having the same extension. You would then generate (with javascript) a random number between 1 and n and change the src of your image to point to that random file. Something like this randomly chooses between 1 and 10 and looks for the image in the same folder as the html (you could of course add some conditions to make sure you're not trying to display an image that's not in your folder):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var url = random + ".jpg";
            $("#my_image").attr("src", url);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="my_image" src="1.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

As I said, this aims to be a simple solution, definitely not the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP based solution. You can read all the files in the folder into an array using this code:

```
$allFiles = scandir("path/to/images");
$files = array_diff($allFiles, array('.', '..')); // removes "." and ".." from the list
```

Then you can use this code to get a new number for each day:

```
$index = date('z')%count($files);
```

The first half of that takes the day of the year (0 to 365) and the second half does the modulus using the number of files you have (if you have 10 files, it will give you 0 to 9; if you have 100 files, it will give you 0 to 99; etc.).

Then it's a simple matter of using that image, like this:

```
echo('<img src="path/to/images/' . $files[$index] . '" />');
```

This does have limitations: it assumes that the folder contains your images and nothing else, and it will only show the first 365 images, but it should be a good starting point for you.